# C++ use regex on char array with \0's and get result

Tags: c++, regex

I want to use regex on a binary file, which contains 0 bytes, which renders me unable to use a string. I'm using a char array, and I'm able to use regex on the char array.

Buffer is a copy of the file mapped into memory, and read is the total size. This code works, but now I want to get the result back from the function. How do I do this?

```
    if(std::regex_search(buffer, buffer + read, *params->pattern))
    {
        std::cout << "Found.";
    }
```

Comment: can you simply remove the \0s and just match the whole string?

Comment: There are quite a few files I have to do this on in a regular interval, it would probably decrease performance quite a bit.

Also I don't see why that would be nessecairy it would render the function useless when using iterators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test this but it should work..

```
auto it = std::cregex_iterator(&buffer[0], &buffer[read], *params->pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < it->size(); ++i)
{
    const char* str = (*it)[i].str();
    size_t size = (*it)[i].length();

    std::cout.write(str, size);
}
```

I've tested this only on regular strings.. Not strings containing null chars. I don't see why it shouldn't work though because it does return a sequence of chars and the length of said sequence.

Comment: It works, but for some reason the first character of the result is left out. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: Hm, seems to leave out the first character when using .c_str()

Comment: Hmm.. must be your regex OR the data being fed. I cannot see it removing any characters (especially the first char). I tried this with regular strings a while back and it matched fine.